# Constructor DTO container pattern

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, dto

Has anyone seen a pattern whereby Java constructor parameters are created using a DTO object and then injected into the class using Spring? I believe it is an anti-pattern but am curious if there is a reasonable case where it could be used.

In my mind the ideal thing to do is refactor the code so the need for the single constructor object is redundant.

What's everyones thoughts?

My particular example is of the form:

```
@Service
public class MyClass {

    private MyClassConstructorDto constructorDependencyContainer;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(MyClassConstructorDto constructorDependencyContainer) {

        this.constructorDependencyContainer = constructorDependencyContainer;
    }


    public void doSomething() {

        constructorDependencyContainer.getCoolDependency().performThing();
    }
}
```

with supporting class

```
@Component
public class MyClassConstructorDto {

    private CoolDependency coolDependency;

    public MyClassConstructorDto(CoolDependency coolDependency) {

        this.coolDependency = coolDependency;
    }

    public CoolDependency getCoolDependency() {

        return coolDependency;
    }
}
```

Comment: An approach would to have in `MyClass` fields which are used by `MyClass` methods, then pass the `MyClassConstructorDto` in the constructor and initialize the fields of `MyClass` with values from `MyClassConstructorDto` this way the `MyClass` constructor parameters will not grow while adding new values which are used in `MyClass` and `MyClassConstructorDto` methods are not called every time when a method of `MyClass` is called

Comment: This is exactly what is happening. My worry is that by encapsulating the dependencies then the amount of dependencies can easily grow too large without a short feedback loop to highlight this which would easily be solved by removing the constructor DTO object completely. I'm wondering if anyone has seen this pattern work for a large system?

Comment: I've seen it implemented in a white label e-commerce platform where in the constructor of the service beans specific config classes were injected and the constructors were initializing the fields. Indeed this solution hides the design issue of too many responsibilities of a bean (so the opposite of single responsibility principle)

Comment: It might make sense in an application which is the frontend of a microservices platform, but this solution is a bit taken to the limit. I can detail more the use case if is of interest, just let me know